# I remaked console app to WinForm app. I can't get output from another console app now

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I had C# console app, which runs another Borland C console app.  It worked okay.
But after I remake the first  app to WinForm app, I can't get output from Borland C console app.

Code is here:

```
Process p = new Process();    
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;    
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;    
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;    
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;    
p.StartInfo.FileName = name1;    
p.Start();    
StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;    
progOutput = sr.ReadToEnd();    
//progOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();    
p.WaitForExit();
```

The string `progOutput` is empty.  I get the same result if I use line
`progOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` instead of `StreamReader`

Borland C console app really started and created it's output files normally.
But it's output disappeared in WinForm app.
As I said this code worked okay in C# console app, 
but does not work now in C# Windows Form app.

BTW, if I run C# console app in WinForm app, output is okay.
Somehing wrong with Borland C output?
But it worked when I ran Borland C app in  C# console app.
So I am puzzled.

Thanks

Comment: What does StandardError have?

Answer (score 1):

In some scenarios I found beneficial to launch executables indirectly like so..

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + name1;
```

..especially when having output redirect issues. But you say it worked as a console app?!

Comment: I was having this same issue! This fixed it for me!

Comment: Replace `p.StartInfo.FileName = name1;` with the 2 lines above and tell us the results..

Comment: But how can I send arguments to the console program? And what does "/C" means. Thanks. BTW, I solved the problem with one trick for  now. I created *.bat files with the following inside<br> myBorlandProg.exe %1 %2 > myBorlandProg.log<br/> Then I analyse this log file

Answer (score 0):

check

```
var errorOut = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

you might get output as StandardError. You can find many questions related to this, we expect output from StandardOutput but it redirect to StandardError.